# Kendo multiselect, trigger an event when an item is removed

Tags: events, kendo-ui, multi-select

I use the multiselect from the Kendo UI. 
I want to know if there is any way to trigger a function, when the user deletes an item from the multiselect.
So far I know that the 'change' event is triggered, but it is too generic and I can't find any info on what the user removed. Or is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about define `change` as:

```
change    : function (e) {
    var previous = this._savedOld;
    var current = this.value();
    var diff = [];
    if (previous) {
        diff = $(previous).not(current).get();
    }
    this._savedOld = current.slice(0);
    // diff has the elements removed do whatever you want...
}
```

What I do is save previous values on `_savedOld` and then compute the difference with current using [jQuery.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/). It's important to note the use of `slice` for cloning previous list of values, if we save `current` then we are actually saving a reference to current list and since it is a reference next time we try to use we get again current value.

**EDIT**: In order to save the values set during the initialization, you can do:

```
dataBound : function (e) {
    saveCurrent(this);
},
change    : function (e) {
    var previous = this._savedOld;
    var current = this.value();
    var diff = $(previous).not(current).get();
    saveCurrent(this);
    // diff has the elements removed do whatever you want...
}
```

where `saveCurrent` is a function defined as:

```
function saveCurrent(multi) {
    multi._savedOld = multi.value().slice(0);
}
```

Comment: Works but not always. Sometimes I initialize the multiselect, and set some values to it with .values().
So then, if I remove one of them, it triggers 'change' but previous is undefined.

Comment: `multiselect.trigger('change');` 
seems to do the trick after setting the values manually...

Comment: Right, in addition, save `values` in `dataBound` for covering the initialization case. See my **EDIT**.

Comment: how can i know which item was deleted? Im really stuck here mates